# Continuity Concept of Multivariable Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multivariate-polynomial

I have recently started going into limits and continuity of multivariable functions and I was just wondering if there is an easy way to determine the continuity of various functions (e.g. polynomial, exponential, rational) in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

For instance,
$$f(x, y) = x+y^{2},$$
$$f(x, y) = e^{x+y},$$
$$f(x, y) = \frac{x+y}{x-y}$$

Are all these functions continuous over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? How do one determine so?

My hunch is that since the first equation is a polynomial function of two variables, it is continuous. The second equation is a composition of the exponential function with a polynomial function of two variables, hence it is also continuous. The last one is a rational function, so rather than being continuous over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, it is continuous over the domain?

Can anyone confirm this for me?

Comment: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(Apex)/12%3A_Functions_of_Several_Variables/12.02%3A_Limits_and_Continuity_of_Multivariable_Functions

Comment: If you're just starting out : in two or three months (or even now) you can probably know that the functions are continuous on their respective domains at a glance (it's true, they're all continuous on their domain). The trouble with continuity is not really posed by functions like these, but more anomalous functions such as infinite summations, functions with integrals, or implicitly defined functions (derived as roots of appropriate equations e.g. $x^2+f(x,y)^3y^3x+\ln f(x,y) = 0$). If you ask about those functions, then this question is too broad. Else, it's quite meek.